# javascript function argument in ie9

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am trying to iterate an array using the .each functionality from the [Node Web Toolkit](https://github.com/orgs/nwtjs) framework. while I do that, am passing each element of the array as:

```
arrayName.each(function(ele){
    console.log(ele);
    //or
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

That gives me `null` or empty in IE9. Can anyone tell me how to pass the each *ele* of the array as a argument to the function? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `.each` is a jQuery function. Javascript uses `.forEach`. Try that

Answer (score 0):

How does the 'arrayName' variable look like? nwtjs.each method iterates on a special node collection (looking for a 'nodes' property within it), so you cannot iterate on a normal array.
As their example shows up: http://nwtjs.github.io/nwt/manual.html - **Node Collections section**, you firstly need to get a reference to a node collection so you can iterate it using .each:

```
// Creating a new collection
var els = n.all('#mymenu li');

// Iterate over each item in the collection
// Receives each element as an argument
els.each(function(el){
    console.log(el);
});
```

Comment: Trying that in ie9 i.e., console.log(els) will give **undefined**;

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from the documentation directly. Did you check into it. Please try this code.

```
// Creating a new collection
var els = n.all('#mymenu li');

// Iterate over each item in the collection
// Receives each element as an argument
els.each(function(el){
  console.log(el);
});
```

http://nwtjs.github.io/nwt/manual.html

Comment: `n.all('div.btn-group').each(function (els){
  console.log(els);
  els.on('keyup', function(e) {
   console.log('e---->',e)
  })
 })`

Here **els** is undefined :( only in ie9